# How to detect sound from microphone in .net

Tags: c#, .net, audio

I currently have code to create webcam that sits in free space and automajically moves up or down depending on a flag that I set by pressing a key on the keyboard. *I want to be able to make it so that if sound is detected on the microphone (above a certain threshold so it doesn't just pick up noise) then the flag gets set to true. If the sound stops, (falls below threshold) the flag will go false and the moving will stop.* I have all the components except for detecting sound from microphone and triggering an event.

Any help you guys can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, the Clapper.  Clap on!  Clap off!  US patent #5493618, http://www.wikipatents.com/US-Patent-5493618/method-and-apparatus-for-activating-switches-in-response-to-different

Answer (score 4):

Please see CheckSilent method from http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip73 example

Comment: NOTE: This is a paid product. The free version has a modal popup on every application start.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundCatcher.aspx

Comment: I downloaded compiled and ran but doesnt work?

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I am using .net 4.0 but this problem occurs when I download his sample .exe as well

Comment: That's odd.  It runs on my machine, but I'm still on Windows XP, .NET 3.5