# WP7 Noise detection - record audio

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, windows-phone

I would like to record audio to know the noise level.

I do not need much precision, only strong noise. How can I know the amplitude of the sound ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You record audio with the XNA-Class Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Microphone:
http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/recording-audio-in-silverlight-on-windows-phone-7/

If you want to detect the noise level, try one of this approaches:

[How to detect sound from microphone in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368035/how-to-detect-sound-from-microphone-in-net)

[Given an audio stream, find when a door slams (sound pressure level calculation?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499795/given-an-audio-stream-find-when-a-door-slams-sound-pressure-level-calculation)