# Start audio recording when microphone is active?

Tags: c#, audio

I need to make simple program, but I am already stuck on my research, I need to make a simple program that will automatically start audio recording from a microphone when someone starts speaking, so the question is is there any way to detect when someone starts speaking into microphone, so later we can start recording audio into file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect sound from microphone in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368035/how-to-detect-sound-from-microphone-in-net)

Comment: You capture audio using one of the available APIs, analyze stream trying to tell whether it's enough of speaking is in there, when the answer is yes you trigger start of recording and process the same captured data respectively.

Comment: Oh, didn't saw that, Thanks for the link. ill try it out!